# Error: Cannot convert from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, file-upload, azure-functions

I'm trying to create Azure function which takes image file from html form POST request and saves it to Blob Storage for further usage with another function. Here is my code:

```
public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            foreach (var file in req.Form.Files)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var file2 = req.Form.Files[0];
                    await file2.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
                "AccountName=mystorageaccount;" +
                "AccountKey=8Hk5k6j65j5j665j67k==;" +
                "EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

                    // intialize BobClient 
                    Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient blobClient = new Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient(
                        connectionString: connectionString,
                        blobContainerName: "image-storage",
                        blobName: "images");

                    // upload the file
                    blobClient.Upload(file2);
                }
            }

            return new OkResult("Image uploaded successfully");
        }
    }
```

However this raises exception:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Any advise would be very highly appreciated.

Edit: I have previously created Blob Container "image-storage" to my storage account using Azure Portal.

Comment: Should pass your `MemoryStream` `ms` to `bobClient.Upload`; `bobClient.Upload(ms);`

Comment: To expand on @pfx comment, essentially change your this line of code `blobClient.Upload(file2);` to `blobClient.Upload(ms)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BlobCient`s [Upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.upload?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClient_Upload_System_IO_Stream_) method expects a `Stream` instead of an `IFormFile`.

Passing the `MemoryStream` you have in the `ms` variable will resolve the issue.

```
blobClient.Upload(ms);
```